# What is the good solution for a bit masking issue?

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation, bitmask

**The Problem**

- I would like to change a bit combination to an other combination without affecting other bits.
- In this combination some bits must be **unset** or **set**

**Question:** what is the best *masking solution*. Especially for the *unset* masking.I

An example: changing bits[3:0] -> 0b1011 (data)
            purpose bits[3:0] ->  0b0110

Let me share what I tried:

- Created an unset mask: 1's complement of 0b1001 --> [1111]0110 (to change the don't cared bits to 1)
- Created the mask: 0b0110

And with this two masks I could use the bitwise operations.

```
int data = 0xB;         /*0b1011 (0xb) -> 0110 (0x6)*/
int umask = 0x9;        /*unset mask 0b1001*/
int smask = 0x6;       /*Set Mask 0b0110*/

data &= ~umask;        /*Unset the bits what needs without affecting other*/
data |= smask;         /*Set the bits what needs to be set*/
```

Comment: You're asking for a generic solution? Or to know if another (better) solution other than your proposed solution for those set values exists?

Comment: What you describe is exactly how it's typically done. Your compiler will do the rest.

Comment: Very common pattern on microcontrollers (e.g. AVRs) when bit twiddling. A line like `PORTB |= 1 << 2;` will get turned into a single `SBI` set-bit assembly instruction.

Comment: Define best.  The above works great as long as you aren't worrying about atomicity.  If you are, there are some additional step to take, but your mask code stays mostly the same.  Also, your compiler should be able to figure out if your system has a better assembly opcode to do what you want just from your code as well.

Comment: One last thought, if you know which bits are already set, you can use xor to twiddle each bit to its end goal in one instruction - `1011 ^ 1100 == 0110`  Rarely do you know the starting state though, so this is often less optimal.

Comment: In my case I need to define two masks? Maybe this should be the main question

Comment: If you need to change bits to both off and on, you need 2 masks.  One to clear and one to set.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is yes, you use 1 mask to clear the bits you want to clear, and another to set the ones you want set.  But, occasionally, there are hidden hardware level things you need to be aware of, depending on how the masks and data are used and what they represent.

If you just want to set your 4 bits to a value:

```
val &= ~(0xf); // This only clears the low 4 bits, preserving the rest.

assert((new4BitMaskvalue & ~0xf) == 0); // Make sure new mask only plays with low 4 bits.
val |= new4BitMaskvalue;  // or new mask
```

You are technically clearing some extra bits, but this allows you to use just one generic mask on clearing.  You can also clear the exact bits as you do, but this may not be necessary.

Often you can just assign the whole value and save a step if you are setting all fields at once in a memory unit size supported by your CPU.  (u8/u16/u32/u64/etc.)

Now, the "fun" part.  If these bits represent actual hardware registers, you may not be able to set entire fields like this as it can cause exciting behavior. Perhaps this is an interrupt enable register.  If so, clearing and resetting bits that don't need clearing and setting will cause unintended side effects.  Also, registers are often read or write only, where again you need to be careful on how you mask and may even be forced to set or clear individual bits one at a time.

In short, yes, you usually need at least 2 values to clear and set bits.  The first `not and` mask can generally be allowed to clear all bits you care about so that you don't need 2 special masks.

Comment: Yes, my main question is around register bit manipulation, but first I wanted to understand this problem, before I try that.

Comment: You may already be saying this in fewer words but it is very important.  It is a good idea if you are using pointer magic such that you have a pointer to a hardware register myreg that when you use it actually touches the register myreg &= ~0x7; myreg|=0x2;  you would have changed those bits then changed them again, you want to make a copy  temp=myreg; temp&=~0x7; temp|=0x2; myreg=temp. So understand the access method.  If this is simply data in a variable then as stated and as you figured out you need an and to zero bits and an or to set bits.